# GCS won't copy or move a file

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

4.2This code has been working in a GAE app for months to copy a file from one bucket to another:

```
// Following is called in constructor
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService( RetryParams.getDefaultInstance() );

private void copy( GcsFilename src, GcsFilename dst ) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        gcsService.copy( src, dst );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        logger.error( e.getMessage() );
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Early today it suddenly stops working.  The src file is left in its place and no exception is thrown.  What is happening?

This also occurred several months ago.  It was never resolved.  The fix was to simply update to a current version of GCS Client Library for Java.  I hate to think that is the fix again.  Currently using gcs client 0.4.2.

Comment: No exception is thrown, but it also doesn't do anything? Perhaps it's not being called. Maybe add a log statement to check?

Comment: I've added a log statement directly above the call to gcsService.  I can see it being executed.  Also, nothing has changed in the app.  Yesterday it simply stopped working (ie. files were not longer copied).